# Align the text to middle of div

Tags: html, css

Basically I am trying to align the "View Full Article (0 Comments)" text to the middle of the arrow in the dark blue div on the below linked page.

I have tried line height and that doesn't work. Any ideas?

http://www.prxa.info/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how fancy you want to get, I would just use relative/absolute positioning here, so this does the trick

```
.articles-bottom { position: relative; }

.articles-bottom a { left: 30px; position: absolute; top: 7px; }
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

try applying following to your a tag:

```
.articles-bottom a
{    
   vertical-align: middle;
   line-height: 2em;
   float: left; 
}
```

and for `img` inside `div`

```
img{
    float:left;
}
```

hope this helps.